Tradingview indicator that include another indicator
This is my basic indicator:
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adc
//@version=5
indicator(title='L44', overlay=true)
res = input.timeframe(title = "Timeframe", defval = '')
offset = input.int(title = "Offset", minval = 0, defval = 0)

line = (open[0] close[0])/2
line2 = (close[0] + close[1])/2

L = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, line[offset])
L2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, line2[offset])

Now I wish to create a new indicator that calls up only the L2 value of the old indicator but I cannot figure out how to do it.
